# django-jqgrid, how do i show a field from a fk relation in the grid?

Tags: javascript, django, jqgrid

I'd like to use the grid to show data for stock reservations. For each reservation i like to show type, quantity and reservation date, there can be multiple types of reservations and the type definitions are stored in a related table.

I try to show a field in related table, fk, in the grid but the grid column stays empty. In the grid.py i have defined the field type__typename field and i get a column in the grid but no data. The id, quantity and reservationdate fields are showing up correctly in the grid.

As far as i can understand from the source, jqgrid.py in the function lookup_foreign_key_field, one should name the field in the grid class as fk__field.

Im using Django 1.5, jquery-1.9.1 and postgesql 9.2

Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated.

grid.py

```
class StockReservationsGrid(JqGrid):
    model = StockReservations # could also be a queryset
    fields = ['id', 'type__typename','quantity', 'reservationdate'] # optional     
    caption = 'Reservations' # optional
    colmodel_overrides = {
        "id": { "editable": False, "width":10, "rowNum": 5, },  
        "type__typename": {'index': 'type__typename', 'label':'Type'},
    }

    def __init__(self, request, stockitem_id):
        super(StockReservationsGrid, self).__init__()
        self.queryset = StockReservations.objects.filter(
            type__isnull=False,warehouse__isnull=False, stockitem_id=stockitem_id)
        self.url = reverse_lazy('stock_reservations_grid', args = [stockitem_id])
```

views.py

```
def stock_reservations_grid(request, stockitem_id):
    grid = StockReservationsGrid(request, stockitem_id)
    return HttpResponse(grid.get_json(request), mimetype="application/json") 

def stock_reservations_grid_config(request, stockitem_id):
    # build a config suitable to pass to jqgrid constructor   
    grid = StockReservationsGrid(request, stockitem_id)
    return HttpResponse(grid.get_config(), mimetype="application/json")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('Warehouse.views',       
    url(r'^stock_reservations_grid/(?P<stockitem_id>\d+)/$', 
        stock_reservations_grid, 
        name='stock_reservations_grid'),
    url(r'^stock_reservations_grid/cfg/(?P<stockitem_id>\d+)/$', 
        stock_reservations_grid_config, 
        name='stock_reservations_grid_config'),           
)
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("{% url "stock_reservations_grid_config" stockitem.id %}", function(data){
        $("#deliverydata_grid")
            .jqGrid(data)
            .navGrid('#deliverydata_pager', 
                {add: false, edit: false, del: false, view: true},
        {}, // edit options
        {}, // add options
        {}, // del options 
        { multipleSearch:true, closeOnEscape:true }, // search options 
        { jqModal:false, closeOnEscape:true} // view options 
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

data

```
{"rowList": [10, 25, 50, 100], 
 "sortname": "id", 
 "viewrecords": true, 
 "autowidth": true, 
 "shrinkToFit": true, 
 "height": "auto", 
 "gridview": true, 
 "sortorder": "asc", 
 "rowNum": 10, "pager": "#pager", 
 "jsonReader": {"repeatitems": false}, 
 "altRows": true, 
 "caption": "Reservations", 
 "datatype": "json", 
 "rownumbers": false, 
 "forcefit": true, 
 "url": "/warehouse/reservations/stock_reservations_grid/147/", 
 "colModel": [{"index": "id", 
               "name": "id", 
               "width": 10, 
               "rowNum": 5, 
               "editable": false, 
               "label": "ID"}, 
              {"index": "type__typename", 
               "name": "type__typename", 
               "editable": true, 
               "label": "Type"}, 
              {"index": "quantity", 
               "editable": true, 
               "name": "quantity", 
               "label": "quantity"},
              {"index": "reservationdate", 
               "editable": true, 
               "name": "reservationdate", 
               "label": "reservationdate"}]}
```

models.py

```
class STB():
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey('Warehouse.Warehouse', null=True)
    stockitem = models.ForeignKey('Stockitems.Stockitems', null=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0) 
    transactiondate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(EST()))  

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

 class StockresTypes():
        typeno = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
        typename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __unicode__(self):            
                return u'%s %s' % (self.typeno, self.typename)

class Meta:        
    ordering = ['typename']    
    app_label = 'Warehouse'        

class StockReservations(STB):
    type = models.ForeignKey('StockresTypes', null=True, db_index=True)
    reservationdate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(EST()))
    sourceid = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)


    def __unicode__(self):            
        return u'%s %s %s %s' % (
            self.type, self.warehouse, self.stockitem, self.reservationdate)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['reservationdate', 'warehouse', 'stockitem']    
        app_label = 'Warehouse'
```

json.json

```
 {"rows": [{"transactiondate": "2013-05-09T16:51:52.191Z", 
            "stockitem_id": 2812, 
            "id": 2169, 
            "type_id": 1, 
            "reservationdate": "2009-04-17T22:00:00Z", 
            "warehouse_id": 56, 
            "quantity": "2.00"}], 
            "total": 1, "page": 1, "records": 1}
```

Comment: You have problem in the part `$("#deliverydata_grid").jqGrid(data)` of your code. You should understand that it's **the main part**. You posted no information about **how you use** jqGrid. You have to include full `data` value : full parameters and the data which you use to fill the grid.

Comment: @Oleg, i have added the requested information but UI'm not really sure the problem is in the $("#deliverydata_grid").jqGrid(data). The jason that is sent to the grid lacks the typname field.

Comment: The data from `json.json` don't contains any information for `"type__typename"`, so you have here pure **server side problem**. The server have to fill the data.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve a similar issue by using the jqgrid bundled in django gems package: http://plfiorini.github.io/django-gems/ Just download it, unzip and run

> python setup.py install

Then in the grids.py, remove the older jqgrid import and use the jqgrid from django gems by `from django_gems.jqgrid import JqGrid`. Now your Json should have the foreign key data.